# is the Linux NTFS implementation journaled?

Tags: linux, ntfs, journaling

I read somewhere that Linux NTFS implementation, in my specific case Raspbian (base on Debian), is not journaled but I didn't find confirm that it is true

if it is true there is a way to have it journaled?

now I'm using it on a USB stick for Windows compatibility

if it is not true I'd use ext4 instead to prevent corruption due to sudden power loss

Comment: can you elaborate? why are you concerned about journaling? NTFS is Windoze FS and all in all, has some journaling itself, see: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130101-00/?p=5673 but that has nothing to do with UNIX journaling.

Comment: I know that Windows NTFS has journaling, my question is whether even the Linux NTFS implementation has it, or I should use ext4 to have more corruption protection from sudden power loss

Comment: You should use ZFS or XFS if you're really worried about that.

Answer (score 0):

In the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ntfs-3g), two mount options are presented:

> `recover`
>   Recover and try to mount a partition which was not unmounted properly by Windows. The Windows logfile is cleared, which may cause inconsistencies. Currently this is the default option.
>
> `norecover`
>   Do not try to mount a partition which was not unmounted properly by Windows.

which would imply the NTFS fuse driver implementation does partial recovery of the journal, but a crude and not so reliable one.

On Linux, I would *always* use a Linux native FS like ext4, xfs or btrfs, if you want your files to be safe.